# how to get checkbox checked data in vbscript to a html table from xml

Tags: html, xml, vbscript

here is my vbscript code

1. my requirement  to display the data in table
2. in my page i have some checkboxes when i check some of them whose status is "Closed"
   and click on  a button ....then i need to get the table with checkbox checked ones
   (whose status is closed) and rest of all status should display...
3. now how can i get that checkd checkbox data.

```vb
sXML4= goBO.QueryXML("SELECT ISS_REL_ID, ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ISS_RANK , 106),'NA') AS DATEREPORTED,ISS_TITLE AS ISSUESREPORT,ISS_IMPACT AS REPORTEDBY, "&_
                           " ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ISS_TRG_RS_DATE , 106),'NA') AS DATECLOSED, "&_
                           " C_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY, "&_
                           " CASE WHEN ISS_STATUS ='C' THEN 'Closed' WHEN ISS_STATUS ='O' THEN 'Work In Progress' WHEN ISS_STATUS ='K' THEN 'KIV'END AS "&_
                           " STATUS, ISS_PROGRESS_RPT, "&_
                           " CASE WHEN ISS_STATUS ='C' THEN 'GREEN' WHEN ISS_STATUS ='O' THEN 'ORANGE' WHEN ISS_STATUS ='K' THEN 'ORANGE'END AS COL "&_
                           " FROM v_iss_list WHERE  ISS_PROGRESS_RPT='Y' and ISS_REL_ID = 'prj0000152' order by status ","TYPES","TYPE")


On Error Resume Next
if goBO.HasError then HandleError

Set oXML4 = Server.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
oXML4.async = false
oXML4.loadXML sXML4
For each oNode4 in oXML4.documentElement.childNodes

    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<tr>"
    'sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""center"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11"">&nbsp;<label><input type=""checkbox"" value=""Yes"" name=""myTextEditBox""""></label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline

    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11"">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("DATEREPORTED") &"</label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline
    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11"">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("ISSUESREPORT") &"</label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline
    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11"">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("REPORTEDBY") &"</label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline
    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11"">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("DATECLOSED") &"</label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline
    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11"">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("CATEGORY") &"</label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline

    if oNode4.getAttribute("STATUS") = "Closed" then
       dim val
       val =  oNode4.getAttribute("ISSUESREPORT") 

       sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11;background-color:"& oNode4.getAttribute("COL") &""">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("STATUS") &"&nbsp<input type=""checkbox""  name=""myTextEditBox"" value=""yes""""></label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline
    else 
       sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "<td align=""left"" style=""font-family:verdana;font-size:11;background-color:"& oNode4.getAttribute("COL") &""">&nbsp;<label>"& oNode4.getAttribute("STATUS") &"</label>&nbsp</td>" + vbNewline
    end if 
    sDataPoint4 = sDataPoint4 + "</tr>" + vbNewline

Next

'bp oXML4.documentElement.childNodes(0).getAttribute("ISSUESREPORT")  

Set oXML4 = nothing
set oBO = nothing



SUB GetResults(myTextEditBox)

    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
        IF myTextEditBox.Checked = TRUE THEN
            MSGBOX myTextEditBox.Value
        END IF
        IF ERR.Number <> 0 THEN
            FOR i = 0 TO myTextEditBox.Length - 1
                IF myTextEditBox(i).Checked = TRUE THEN
                     MSGBOX myTextEditBox(i).Value
                END IF
            NEXT
        END IF
    ON ERROR GOTO 0
END SUB
```

can some body help me...

Thank you